# Should the hover event be disabled once a link is clicked?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, hover

As I was working on the link styling for this page [component-header](https://superflycss.github.io/component-header/target/test/html/) I noticed that the hover event was not triggering.  I then opened the page up in incognito mode, and the link `:hover` styling renders.

So the browser (Both Chrome and Firefox) remember that you have visited a certain link (Regardless of whether it's a new tab), and after that the browser does not trigger the hover event.

I was expecting that event to be triggered regardless of whether the link has been visited or not.  I do expect the `:visited` style to be displayed once the link is visited, but if the mouse hovers, I would just naturally expect that the `:hover` style be triggered.

I filed a [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=738614#c18) with Chrome for this I'm just wondering whether I should follow up on it or whether the current behavior is there for a good reason?

It seems like we should not have to remember the right order for Pseudo selectors, although the clever tip offered by @kapreski makes it very easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After visited the `:visited` rule overwrites the `:hover` rule, if the `:hover` is before the ":visited".

The `:hover` works in any case if it comes after the `:visited` rule in the css file, or if the `:hover` has the `!important` clause.

Comment: Ahh - Source order dependent - Good eye - thanks.  I updated the design of the component and it renders both before and after the click now.

Answer (score 1):

just to add a tip to the accepted answer that makes remembering the order of the four selectors a bit easier, just think of "love (lv) hate (ha)"

```
  a:link
  a:visited
  a:hover
  a:active
```